# Adding custom parameter to django modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm having troubles adding a custom parameter to a modelform (in this case, the currrent user from request.user)
I used to do this on previous projects, and I can't manage to make it work on a new project on Django 1.10.4.

I got this error :

```
TypeError at /realestateprogram/edition_appartement/19/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

This is my view :

```
apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ApartmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=apartment, user=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('list_realestateprogram_apartment', realestateprogram_id=apartment.realestateprogram.id)
    else:
        print form.errors
else:
    form = ApartmentForm(instance=apartment, user=request.user)
```

and this is my form :

```
class ApartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Apartment
        exclude = ('realestateprogram',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ApartmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks in advance if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass all the values with keyword arguments:

```
form = ApartmentForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=apartment, user=request.user)
```

If you look at the [class based generic views](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.4/django/views/generic/edit.py#L47), that's how they do it. I would also suggest that you look at [Form handling with class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does not work either when I pass all the values with keyword args :/